# Does the Heroku memory limit include the memory required to run the OS?

Tags: heroku

Does Heroku's memory limit include the memory required to run the OS (as compared to having the entire memory quota of 512MB/1024MB available to run the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Heroku's memory limit includes the memory required to run the OS.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do you have a reference? It seems documentation on this topic is really hard to find on their site/on most forums. So this means that depending on what is already installed on their Ubuntun 10.04 Cedar stack, I might only have 200MB available to my application?

Comment: Heroku is built using LXC (http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) containers (reference is https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). I'm not sure it includes an entire OS more a virtualised subsystem but knowing it's LXC based may point you in a good direction.